# odd javascript remembrance in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following in index.html:

```
<html><body><pre>
<script src="program.js"></script>
</pre></body></html>
```

And the following in program.js:

```
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(name));
name = "Bob";
```

Opening index.html for the first time, this is produced (output A):

```
> ""
```

Then, after refreshing the page, this is produced (output B):

```
> "Bob"
```

I do not ever see output B in Firefox.

Going back to Chrome: if, however, I use some variable other than 'name', such as 'val':

```
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(val));
val = "Bob";
```

I get an exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined
```

So, since 'name' happens to be in the global scope, I thought that Chrome was somehow remembering global variables from old page loads, and setting default values of the those variables in new page loads. But, if I use the global variable 'status' instead, I always see output A.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Oh I just managed to reproduce it. Interesting enough.

Comment: I observe the same behavior in incognito mode.

Comment: Out of interest, if you have two different pages with the same code, does it remember the value cross-page? That'd be especially serious...

Comment: It looks like the name we are changing the name of the window object. And it is persisted as long as the window is opened. May need further investigations

Comment: Yes you're setting the [`name`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqvfija.php) of the `window` object as the `window.` namespace is implicit when you use the global scope.

Comment: If someone makes that an answer I'll upvote them.

Comment: I'm not good explaining this kind of thing and the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#dfn-name) doesn't say a word about the persistence of the property (even though that might be considered a little obvious), it is the case for Chrome and Firefox at least.

Comment: Actually, it looks like that W3C spec does give a hint: "The name attribute of a Window object MUST be the name assigned by the embedding element, the empty string if there is no such element or a value set by the script author. How this name is extracted from the embedding element is language specific."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `name` variable in the global context is some kind of reserved name in chrome. The same is applicable for variables like `status` as they can take only `String` values.

This `name` attribute refers to the name of the window object, which is persisted as long as the window is alive, so the value is shared between multiple documents.

Ex: `var status = {}; alert(status)` will alert `[Object object]` same with `name` also.

I don't have any reference doc to provide for this behaviour but something I noticed as a result in a bug report on one of my project.

Comment: By "shared between multiple documents", are you referring to multiple tabs? If I open index.html in one tab, then open index.html in another tab, I see output A in both of them. I only observe output B on a page after refreshing it.

Comment: looked it up, I don't think it's only chrome, as I found it in the MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.name it's beyond me as to why it behaves differently in firefox and chrome though.

Comment: No. It won't be shared across tabs, only in the tab where name is changed.